# How to sum same valued row until different value come

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like the picture. I want to find min assign date and min escalate date group by operator till different operator is come. Example first two operator is same so i want to sum that two because different operator is come after them.

```
TROUBLETICKETINDEX         OPERATOR         Assign                   Escalate
    1262084                qbcca0110    12-12-2016 21:11:49  12-12-2016 21:11:49
    1262084                qbcca0110    12-12-2016 21:16:23  12-12-2016 21:16:23
    1262084                tss          12-14-2016 1:45:58   12-14-2016 1:45:58
    1262084                qbcca0110    12-14-2016 10:34:31  12-14-2016 10:34:31
```

Please tell me is that possible in mysql?

I am try with this

```
  select th.TROUBLETICKETINDEX,
         th.OPERATOR, 
         min(th.HISTORYDATE) Assign, 
         max(th.HISTORYDATE) Escalate
    from troubleticketshistory th inner join 
         users_usergroups uug on uug.userId = th.TICKETOWNER inner join 
         usergroup ug on ug.userGroupId = uug.userGroupId
   where th.TROUBLETICKETINDEX=1262084
group by th.OPERATOR;
```

but this gives me

[image]

But i am looking for

[image]

This is my troubleticketshistory table

```
HISTORYDATE         OPERATOR    TROUBLETICKETINDEX  TICKETOWNER USERGROUPINDEX
12-12-2016 21:11:49 qbcca0110   1262084                  24229  12016
12-12-2016 21:16:23 qbcca0110   1262084                  25111  22956
12-14-2016 1:45:58  tss         1262084                  24229  12016
12-14-2016 10:34:31 qbcca0110   1262084                  24229  12016
```

Comment: Can you please include sample data in textual format instead of images?

Comment: I mean in your original post.

Comment: Please remove irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT TROUBLETICKETINDEX,
       OPERATOR,
       MIN(HISTORYDATE) AS Assign,
       MAX(HISTORYDATE) AS Escalate
FROM (
   SELECT th.TROUBLETICKETINDEX,
          th.OPERATOR, 
          th.HISTORYDATE
          @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
          @grp := IF(@op = OPERATOR, @grp + 1,
                     IF(@op := OPERATOR, 1, 1)) AS grp
   FROM troubleticketshistory th
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @grp := 0, @op := '') AS vars
   WHERE th.TROUBLETICKETINDEX = 1262084
   ORDER BY th.Assign) AS t
GROUP BY TROUBLETICKETINDEX, OPERATOR, rn - grp 
ORDER BY Assign
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f934618/1)

Comment: Can anyone explain the sub-query?